# Changing value based on a condition in r

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
head(data)
      Date Avg.Join.Delay Min.Join.Dely Max.Join.Dely    ACCOUNT STB_TYPE  MARKET
1 6/5/2015            500           500           500 3036831961  IPH8005  Denver
2 6/5/2015            500           500           500 3038416736  IPH8005  Denver
3 6/5/2015            500           500           500 4802192190  IPH8005 Phoenix
4 6/5/2015            500           500           500 4802193088  IPH8005 Phoenix
5 6/5/2015            500           500           500 4802795632  IPH8005 Phoenix
6 6/5/2015            500           500           500 4803611713  IPH8005 Phoenix
```

I want to change the Account number to a City/State (303 = Colorado), but I am not sure what is the correct syntax of this kind of script.

I tried `data$ACCOUNT[data$ACCOUNT == "303%"] <- "Colorado"` but it doesn't change the value.
Any idea how to do it in a way that it will change all the values that begin with `xxx`?

Comment: Based on the example showed, there is `3036831961` and not `"303%"`.  If it is the first 3 numbers, then `data$ACCOUNT[substr(data$ACCOUNT,1,3)=='303'] <- 'Colorado'`

Comment: I don't know why you thought `%` would work as a wildcard, but that's not how it works in R. If it wasn't simply the first 3 characters you would probably use Regex, and `%` is not a wildcard in Regex.

Comment: % is a wildcard in SQL, I'm guessing that's where OP got the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `substr` to extract the first 3 characters

```
data$ACCOUNT[substr(data$ACCOUNT,1,3)=='303'] <- 'Colorado'
```

Or use `sub`

```
data$ACCOUNT[sub('(.{3}).*', '\\1',data$ACCOUNT)=='303'] <- 'Colorado'
```

Or `grep`

```
data$ACCOUNT[grepl('^303', data$ACCOUNT)] <- 'Colorado'
```